# Directory.GetFiles | Get only the specific file

Tags: vb.net

I want to copy a specific file only but it copies all files in the directory. Is there any way to achieve it?

here is my code:

```
    Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\SERVER-PC\BrokerDatabase\BrokerDatabase\Attachments")

    For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles()
        fi.CopyTo("D:\" + fi.Name)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It copies all files in the directory because you're looping the .CopyTo without any condition. If the filename of the file you are looking for is static, add a condition with it so it won't copy all the files.

```
 Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\SERVER-PC\BrokerDatabase\BrokerDatabase\Attachments")

    For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles()
        If fi.Name = "FileToBeCopied.txt" Then
            fi.CopyTo("D:\" + fi.Name)
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Why would you get every file from a folder and then check every one for the name instead of just getting that file by name in the first place?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot that. If they exactly know which file to copy then it's better to directly reference it instead of looping through the whole directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another (fancy) way,

```
Dim allSeries As IEnumerable(Of String) =
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, file, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If allSeries.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("not found.")
    End If
```

where "root" is a String with the file path, and "file" is a String with the file name